# Add new table to an existing database using database first approach EF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, ef-database-first

Now I'm using EF 6 database first in my solution , I have entities that pre-defined in the database. I now need to update the database and add tables !

I can't find the true way to follow

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open the edmx file and on a black space right click and use **Update Model From Database...**

[image]

Comment: using this solution , i must create the database table at the end-user with SQL Syntax i think ! have you other way to get migrations ?

Comment: @MedMANS As you said you are trying database first, I thought the table already exist. In this case I think you may want to try making the table here in the model (edmx file) and try using Generate Database from Model.

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative and the result is also much cleaner imo, you can also delete the .edmx file completely and remove the database connection string from you projects .config file. Then repeat the process of adding a new edmx file.

Comment: i woul get migrations at the end user also !